# Passing parameter from javascript helper to apex method in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, soql, javascript-controller

This is related to Lightning component framework. Though, I have passed challenge (till 4), however result is not as expected.
I am passing boatTypeId as a parameter from helper-onSearch to apex method-getBoats(). getBoats() return list of boats having the same boatTypeId. Below is my helper and the apex class.

```
({
    onSearch : function(component, event, helper) {
       // console.log('In Helper');
        var action=component.get('c.getBoats');
        var btypeId =component.get("v.boatTypeId");
        console.log('BoatSearchResult helper boattypeId '+btypeId);
        action.setParam({"boatTypeId" :btypeId});
        action.setCallback(this,function(response) {
            if(response.getState() === 'SUCCESS')
            {
                console.log('response from server'+ response.getReturnValue());
                var boatslist = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log('Number of Boats returned'+boatslist.length);
                component.set("v.boats",boatslist);
            } 
            else
            {
                console.log('Error caught in !!!');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

---

```
public with sharing class BoatSearchResults {

    @Auraenabled
    public static List<Boat__c> getBoats(string boatTypeId)
    {
       if(boatTypeId != '')
       {
           system.debug(boatTypeId);
           system.debug('Hello again');
           return ([Select Id, BoatType__c , Contact__r.Name, Name, picture__c from Boat__c Where BoatType__c = :boatTypeId]); 
          // return ([SELECT Id, BoatType__c, picture__c, Name,contact__r.Name from Boat__c]);     
       }
       else
       {
           system.debug('Hello again2');
           return ([SELECT Id, BoatType__c, picture__c, Name,contact__r.Name from Boat__c]);

       }
    }
}
```

Couple of issues here, I find here:

1. boatTypeId passed in the getBoats() is always null
2. If boatTypeId is null , then else part of getBoats() should be executed, but 
   if part of the method is executed all the times. (Maybe I am missing basics 
   of SOQL here)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: system.debug(boatTypeId); is null? did you try passing your parameter with "action.setParams" instead of  "action.setParam" ?

Comment: It's best to use `String.isNotBlank()` instead of the `boatTypeId != ''`. This will check if the `boatTypeId` is null, empty or just whitespace chars. More documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#!     With regards to the parameter passing, @glls is right, use `action.setParams` instead.

Comment: Using action.setParams and String.isNotBlank solved the issue. However, not sure why the boatTypeId != '' (comparison operator to null) , wouldn't work ?

Comment: An empty string is not null (it's a string with a length of zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`action.setParam({"boatTypeId" :btypeId});` here **setParam** is used to set single paramter and you are passing an objet which is not correct. So to make it work either change it to `action.setParams({"boatTypeId" :btypeId});` OR `action.setParam("boatTypeId", btypeId);`

[image: setParam and setParams]

More you can find on the [Aura Documentations site](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:Action).